# Proposed transition matrix for Metropolis-Hastings algorithm in two-state Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose we would like to model the weather (either sunny $S$ or cloudy $C$) using a two-state Markov Chain, given a set of data collected from 10000 days:
$$CCCSSSSSSCCCSSSSSSCCCC...$$

We can use the MCMC Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to get a target transition matrix $P$ whose invariant distribution is given by
$$\pi = \left(\frac{\text{# of $S$'s from the data}}{10000}, \frac{\text{# of $C$'s from the data}}{10000}\right)$$
from the data.

Now how do we choose the proposed transition matrix $Q$? Naturally, we don't want to choose $Q$ to be $$Q = \begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
because then a typical sample from this $P$ would look like
$$CCSCSSCSCSCCSCSCCCSCCS...$$
(which is unrealistic for the weather) instead of our data
$$CCCSSSSSSCCCSSSSSSCCCC...$$

Is there a systematic way of picking the $Q$ given the data set like above? I know the intuition would be say let
$$Q = \begin{pmatrix}
0.9 & 0.1 \\
0.1 & 0.9 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
but the $0.9$ and $0.1$ are still guesses.

Comment: If you knew the stationary distribution then is very easy to obtain the tpm via Meropolis algorithm

Comment: @HungryHomer But the target transition matrix is not unique, I was wondering how we can pick the appropriate proposal transition matrix to get the best target transition matrix that fits the data.